# XMLHttpRequest not well-formed in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have this code to form get XMLHttpRequest:

```
var makeRequest = function () {
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
    var params = 'name=' + encodeURIComponent('123') + '&surname=' + encodeURIComponent('surname')
    xmlhttp.open("GET", 'site.html?' + params, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null)
}
```

And I have this cross-browser function:

```
getXmlHttp = function () {
    var xmlhttp;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
makeRequest()
```

All code is in the local file. No server side.
But Firefox says in console this:

> 'not well-formed'

So what's wrong?

UPD: I have added this `xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/html");`
It doesn'throw an error now but i still can't see it in a web inspector in a firefox
But i can see it in chrome.

Comment: `xmlhttp = false;` It is probably hitting that.

Comment: And btw in chrome it works

Answer (score 2):

It might help if you specified the MIME type.

```
xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/html");
```

or maybe site.html really is incorrectly formed - check opening tags, closing tags, etc...

Comment: It doesn't throw an error now, but in network debugger in firefox I can't see my request(

Comment: You mean you cannot see the body of the request? see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console#HTTP_requests

Comment: Yeah, I still can't see it